# Cannot use property expression in class mediator in WSO2 ESB 4.9.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I created a class mediator and need to use expression for password property because it has been encrypted in vault,

[image: proxy]

However, the property inside of class mediator () seems not support expression. There is an exception in console,

[image: console]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We ran into same issue.  We were unable use expression on a property for the class Mediator.

I am by no means an expert so if there is a better way hopefully someone else will speak up but this is how I got it working.

Change the property on your inSequence to this, really only adding scope="default"

```
<property name="passwordvault"
                   expression="wso2:vault-lookup('proxy.sunb.password')"
                   scope="default"/>
```

Then once you set that you can retrieve it inside nz.govt.mpi.NtlmAuthorisation2 retrieve the value like this

```
password = (String) synMgtx.getProperty("passwordvault");
```

Comment: I cannot comment on why the expression does not work with the class mediator. Above proposed workaround is fine. I am wondering why you need to set the scope as default. Normally, if you define a property in your in sequence, it should be available in the message context. So, can Sean Sun try just retrieving it in the class mediator code.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it is a good workaround. Yes, I can retrieve the passwordvault in the mediator code.